# Generating Filter for Spacial Filtering

Tags: image-processing

I read on Wikipedia and see that if we need to perform spatial filtering on an image, we have to have a filter, for example 3x3, what I don't understand here is how can we choose the value for the filter? Let say that the original image is grey scale so its intensity goes from 0 to 255 (8 bits).

Another question is that if the image is 9x9, how can we apply the filter to boundary pixels of that image? If we choose to pad the image so the filter can work with all boundary pixels, what would be the value for new padded pixels?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the filter depends on what you want to achieve by filtering. There are a lot of filter design to perform a specific task. For example the simplest filter f=[-1  1 -1] kind of perform image derivation by performing first degree differencing on each pixel in horizontal direction (x-derivative) while f' perform the same thing in the vertical (y-derivative). The values -1,1,-1 are choose for such purpose. The same goes for 3*3 filters. In general the choose of the values come from a 2D(bi directional) designing of finite impulse response (FIR) and infinite impulse response (IIR) filters.

You should keep in mind that the value of filter operation on the boarders are not that much accurate. Filtering operation for boarder pixel are done interpolating out-of range pixel by a process called boarder interpolation.In OpenCV and similar image processing/computer vision libraries there are ways to do it. For example as the following in opencv

Various border types, image boundaries are denoted with '|'

- BORDER_REPLICATE:     aaaaaa|abcdefgh|hhhhhhh
- BORDER_REFLECT:       fedcba|abcdefgh|hgfedcb
- BORDER_REFLECT_101:   gfedcb|abcdefgh|gfedcba
- BORDER_WRAP:          cdefgh|abcdefgh|abcdefg
- BORDER_CONSTANT:      iiiiii|abcdefgh|iiiiiii  with some specified 'i'

Thus according to you choose you pad the boarder pixels.